# JQuery - Select input field by type and not readonly

Tags: jquery, readonly

OK, so I have a form and I would like to select a field that is of type "Date" but that does not have a read only attribute. Im sure this is super easy but Im new to js/jq. I would like to do something like this:

```
$('[type="Date"] && [not:readonly]').datepicker();
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `&&` operator, but the selectors are additive by default, similar to CSS:

```
$('[type="date"]:not([readonly])').datepicker();
```